# How to Pass an Array within the View Controller that Array data will Coming From JSON?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, nsmutablearray, uilabel

I have one view controller, with `UIImageView` and `UILabel` in it. How to load image and data to label from JSON by using array? Here is my code

```
-(void)viewDidLoad 
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:"www.example.com"]];
       connection4 = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
      [connection4 start];
}
  -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
  {
   if (connection == connection4)
    {
    myDataQA = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
}
 -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
   {
    if (connection == connection4)
     {
    [myDataQA appendData:data];
     }
  }
  -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
  {
   if (connection == connection4)
     {
    NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myDataQA options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
    fldExamTitleArray = [dic valueForKey:@"fldexamtitle"];
    fldExamStartArray = [dic valueForKey:@"examdate"];
    ListBannerArray =  [dic valueForKey:@"listBanner"];
   }
 }
```

In my code, `ListBannerArray`contains:

"listbanner":"http:demo.example.com/1.png

Answer (score 0):

```
 -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
   {
     if (connection == connection4)
     {
        NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myDataQA options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
       fldExamTitleArray = [dic valueForKey:@"fldexamtitle"];
       fldExamStartArray = [dic valueForKey:@"examdate"];
       ListBannerArray =  [dic valueForKey:@"listBanner"];

     for(int i = 0 ; i < ListBannerArray.count;i++)
       {
           UIImage* myImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:  [ListBannerArray objectAtIndex: i ]]];
           yourimageview.image = myimage;
          your_Label.text = [fldExamTitleArray objectAtIndex : i];
        }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to loop your array and array contain Dictionaries. So you need to get image urls from that dictionary. After that you can load image like that.

```
NSString *ImageURL = @"YourURLHere";
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURL]];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```